# Change a selected buttons icon based on screen size

Tags: jquery, resize, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive website and need the navigation icons to change depending on the screen size.

The navigation bar is pretty much finished now, and the images do change.. but their is a small issue that i'm having, which i replicated in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bundaberg/F3X6k/12/).

Slide the viewport back and forward to see the icons change (i used tinyurl to compress the link, so they'll load a fraction slower.)

So the problem! All focus should be placed on the 'cross' which appears if you click the button (with a screen size less than 600px.)

The cross disappears when the screen viewport is resized above 600px which is good. However! It does not reappear if viewport is scaled back down again.

The only way to get it back is to click the button off and on.

In theory i would be using multiple images for different screen sizes.. but just using one here to keep it simple.

As you can see i've already got a blue and grey image to change depending on the screen size.. but the issue is with getting the selected button to do the same.

Here is the Jquery

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 600px)').matches) {
        $('#settings_button').css({
            "background-image": "url(http://tinyurl.com/oydwfm9)"
        });
    }
    if (matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 601px)').matches) {
        $('#settings_button').css({
            "background-image": "url(http://tinyurl.com/nszbfxl)"
        });
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#settings").hide();


    $("#settings_button").click(function (e) {
        if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 600px)').matches) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $("#settings").toggle();

            if ($('#settings').is(":visible")) {
                $('#settings_button').css({
                    "background-Color": "darkred",
                        "background-image": "url(http://tinyurl.com/odrbvwa)"
                });
            };
            if ($('#settings').is(":hidden")) {
                $('#settings_button').css({
                    "background-Color": "",
                        "background-image": "url(http://tinyurl.com/oydwfm9)"
                });
            };
        }
    });

    $("#settings_button").click(function (e) {
        if (matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 601px)').matches) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $("#settings").toggle();

            if ($('#settings').is(":visible")) {
                $('#settings_button').css({
                    "background-Color": "darkred"
                });
            };
            if ($('#settings').is(":hidden")) {
                $('#settings_button').css({
                    "background-Color": ""
                });
            };
        }
    });
});

$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    $("#settings").hide();

    if ($('#settings').is(":hidden")) {
        $('#settings_button').css({
            "background-Color": "",
                "color": ""
        });
    };
});

$("#settings").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: resize works fine with blue and grey bubbles. BUT once the cross is displayed, even if your are downsizing or upsizing the window, the cross disapear to become a bubble again. The problem is, when you resize your window, the first function handling blue and grey bubbles is called instead the one that must manage the cross. I suggest to set a flag like `blueGreyEnable`. If the sub menu is displayed (button clicked) disable the function that manage blue an grey bubble. LEt me update the fiddle, will be easier ^^

Comment: here it is   http://jsfiddle.net/Bundaberg/F3X6k/12/   you can remove all `console.log` that I have added. If your ok with that, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: That's weird,the 'cross' image was working fine below a width of 600px when i last checked.. i must have included an error somewhere. And this was a copy paste job on my part `($("#settings_button").click(function (e) {)` it's fine to merge them!

I don't understand what you mean by 'set a flag'? My knowledge of jquery is rather lacking :)

Comment: Just checked your link and it is the same one that i posted

Comment: sure ? http://jsfiddle.net/F3X6k/13/

Comment: Hey, that is spot on! I will be happy to label it as best response ;)
To append to my last post.. I wrote all the code, no plagiarism involved. The copy and paste being internal, hence the two `($("#settings_button").click(function (e) {)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comments (that can be usefull for someone else in the future), you must affect the window resizement, depending on the state of the button, clicked or not. I used a `flag` to save the state of the button in a global var, so it can be used in all functions.

http://jsfiddle.net/F3X6k/13/